# jQuery Ajax request returning null in Internet Explorer only

Tags: internet-explorer, jquery

I'm trying to GET an HTML document using the jQuery `ajax()` method.

When I try and parse the returned data using `$(data)` all browsers other than Internet Explorer are returning a DOM element, whereas Internet Explorer is returning NULL.

I've checked 'data' and it's a string as expected.

What might cause this? I'm guessing it could be errors in the markup being pulled in, but I can't spot anything in the validation?

I'm using jQuery 1.4.2.

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: url,
    cache: false,
    contentType: 'html',
    processData: false,
    success: function(data) {
        console.log($(data));
    }
});
```

Comment: Using `$(data)` makes sense only if `data` is valid HTML code. Is it?

Comment: Have you tried explicitly setting `dataType: 'html'`?

Comment: I should probably add that I wish to select a sub selector in the Returned DOM after it's parsed using .find() before injecting the result into the host pages DOM.

Comment: While it's good to provide more information...you haven't answered either of the questions here asking for info that would help you :)

Comment: @Nick there are a couple of minor validation warnings in the HTML. And yes, I've tried dataType: 'html'.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that your [URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator) variable don't link to the [XHTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XHTML) page. Otherwise there are many problems with Internet Explorer.

Comment: If the response is XHTML do you mean?

Comment: Yep, if the response is XHTML, then IE will not parse it into Document object and returns only simple string of the response. To bypass it check the article http://www.hiteshagrawal.com/javascript/convert-xml-document-to-string-in-javascript. The problem is in XHTML, contentType (jQuery) and IE. Hope these will help.